# How to change data type of values in pandas

Tags: pandas

I have a pandas dataframe that has both floats and numpy arrays as follows.

```
   name    x1     x2       X3
0  a       4.7    [0.]     3
1  b       3.2    [1.7]    5
2  e       1.2    [2.]     6
```

I want to change all the numpy values in the dataframe into floats. 
i.e.

```
   name    x1     x2       X3
0  a       4.7    0.       3
1  b       3.2    1.7      5
2  e       1.2    2.       6
```

Can we do that using pandas?

I am happy to provide more details if needed.

Comment: There are only one element lists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If only one element lists use:

```
df['x2'] = df['x2'].str[0]
```

Or:

```
df['x2'] = df['x2'].apply(lambda x: x[0])
```

EDIT:

After comments there are strings in columns, so need:

```
mask = df.iloc[0].astype(str).str.startswith('[')

df.loc[:, mask] = df.loc[:, mask].apply(lambda x: x.str.strip('[]')).astype(float)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for the great answer. However, in my real dataset, I do not know what column names have `numpy`. Is there any way to do this without specifically mentioning the column name? :)

Comment: @Emi - S there are only one element lists?

Comment: @Emi - Or one element arrays in column, or floats ?

Comment: Not sure what you meant. There are multiple columns (say 25 columns) and about 15 of the columns have numpy values :) Please let me know if you want an example. I can update the question.

Comment: @Emi - ya, I think if is possible some value is `[0,2.1]` - length 2 or all arrays have only one value - `[0.]`

Comment: only one value. i.e. `[0.]` :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190706/discussion-between-jezrael-and-emi).